# SQL Reporting Services 2016 Publisher Error

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm getting the following error when trying to connect the SQL Report Publisher RC3 on my laptop to Reporting Services 2016 I'm running on Azure:

> unexpected character encountered while parsing the value <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

I have basic authentication enabled, I can log in from the browser on a different machine. The Report builder 3.0 will not connect either.

Here's the authentication block from my copy of `RSReportingServer.config`:

```
<Authentication>
    <AuthenticationTypes>
        <RSWindowsNegotiate/>
        <RSWindowsBasic>
            <LogonMethod>3</LogonMethod>
            <Realm></Realm>
            <DefaultDomain></DefaultDomain>
        </RSWindowsBasic>
    </AuthenticationTypes>
    <RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>Off</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>
    <RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>Proxy</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>
    <EnableAuthPersistence>true</EnableAuthPersistence>
</Authentication>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Azure image of Windows with SQL Server2016 and reporting services I was using was RC1 and the version of the the Report Publisher 2016 was RC3.  I upgraded all of them to the latest release candidate which I believe was RC4 and it authenticated properly.